# Complex sed Command for Insert Command

Tags: sed, grep, regex, php

I have a bunch of `php` files, which have many `insert` commands.

In each query, I want to insert a column variable `admin_id = '$admin_id'`,
i.e., if the query is

```
insert into users (ch_id, num_value) values ('2', '100')
```

the query should be converted to

```
insert into users (admin_id, ch_id, num_value) values ($admin_id, '2', '100')
```

To do this, I have executed the following command

```
sed -i 's/\(insert.*into.*\) (\(.*values\)/\1 (admin_id, \2/' *.php
```

and

```
sed -i "s/\(insert.*into.*\) values (/\1 values ('\$admin_id', /" *.php
```

The above has worked successfully, but am still facing problem with SQL queries where there is no `where` in the query, i.e.,

```
insert into abctable (id,no)
```

to

```
insert into tablename (admin_id, id, no)
```

and

```
insert into abctable select $column from $tableperiod
```

to

```
insert into abctable select $column from $tableperiod where admin_id='$admin_id'
```

and

```
insert into abctable select $column from $tableperiod where abc != 'xyz'
```

to

```
insert into abctable select $column from $tableperiod where admin_id = '$admin_id' and abc != 'xyz'
```

How can I insert `admin_id` in these queries as well?

The queries in php files are executed by passing the query to the function in the following way:

```
execute_query("insert * from $table order by username");
```

I can find the queries still which are left to be modified by
executing

```
grep 'execute_query' *| grep insert| grep -v admin_id  > stillleft.txt
```

Comment: Hello [again](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253660/complex-sed-command-with-and-or-not/253662).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by using the following command

```
sed -e "s/\(query.*insert.*select.*where\)/& admin_id='\$admin_id' and /g"               -e t \
    -e "s/\(query.*insert.*select.*\)\")/\1  where admin_id='\$admin_id\")'/g"           -e t \
    -e "s/\(query.*insert.*\)(\(.*\)values (/\1(admin_id, \2values ('\$admin_id', /g"    -e t \
    -e "s/\(query.*insert.*(\)/& admin_id, /g"  \
    -i *.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure my testcases are right, but I think this could help you:

I changed the first statement, because I think it's easier and it matches the first and the second command of YOUR sed

```
sed -i 's/\(insert into .* (\)\(.*) values (\)\(.*\)) /\1admin_id, \2\$admin_id, \3/' *.php
```

The second (the first you are looking for) should work with the following

```
sed -i 's/\(insert into .* (\)\(.*) \)/\1admin_id, \2/' *.php
```

And the last two should work with this:

```
sed -i "s/\(insert into \w* select \$column from \$tableperiod\)/\1 where admin_id='\$admin_id'/" *.php
```

I hope this works for you, if not, please send a little bit more test data, if tested the commands with the text of your question as input

Answer (score 0):

I you use multiple sed commands, you'll traverse the complete file each time. You can do it in a single pass. Assuming an input file `infile` that looks like this:

```
insert into users (ch_id, num_value) values ('2', '100')
insert into abctable (id, no)
insert into abctable select $column from $tableperiod
insert into abctable select $column from $tableperiod where abc != 'xyz'
```

we can use the following sed script `sedscr`

```
/^insert into/ {
    s/\(([^)]*)\)(.*)\(([^)]*)\)/(admin_id, \1)\2($admin_id, \3)/
    s/^([^(]+)\(([^)]*)\)$/\1(admin_id, \2)/
    /\(.*\)/! {
        /where/s/$/ and admin_id ='$admin_id'/
        /where/!s/$/ where admin_id='$admin_id'/
    }
}
```

It does the following:

- if a line starts with `insert into`, then

  - for all lines with two pairs of parentheses, insert `admin_id` in the the first one and `$admin_id` in the second one
  - for lines with one pair of parentheses at the end, insert `admin_id`
  - if there are no parentheses, then

    - if there is a "where" clause, append `and admin_id = '$admin_id'`
    - else append `where admin_id='$admin_id'`

This can be called as follows:

```
$ sed -rf sedscr infile 
insert into users (admin_id, ch_id, num_value) values ($admin_id, '2', '100')
insert into abctable (admin_id, id, no)
insert into abctable select $column from $tableperiod where admin_id='$admin_id'
insert into abctable select $column from $tableperiod where abc != 'xyz' and admin_id ='$admin_id'
```

If you can't use extened regular expressions (`-r`), the quoting of parentheses has to be inverted (all `\(` become `(` etc.) and the `+` has to be replaced by `\{1,\}`.

The cumbersome regexes such as `\(([^)]*)\)` stand for "between literal parentheses, capture zero or more characters that are *not* a closing parenthesis" – this enables non-greedy capturing.